# Illustrator CS6 - When I intersect two shapes, remains a line. How I can fix this?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, shapes, pathfinder

I have a little problem with Illustrator CS6.
Like the title says, when I intersect two shapes, remains a line between them.
How can I fix this problem, because I don't want to use another option from the Pathfinder panel.

[image]

Comment: Do you want the letter to be cut-out of the circle (so if it is on a yellow background, the letter K would be yellow as well) or it is supposed to be white?

Comment: do you need the outline?

Comment: Fannie, yea, I want the letter to be cut-out of the circle. Darth_Vader, what outline?

Comment: Does it look the same when you zoom in? when you export? It might just be an on-screen rendering issue.

Comment: Yes, when I zoom in it looks the same. I verified to an other monitor and it persist the problem.

Answer (score 2):

So here's how you go about this:

1. Create the circle and K (I've set 'Show transparency grid' to on in View, so I'll be able to see the white K better)

[image: Create circle and K]

2. Create outlines of the Type

[image: convert Type to outline]

3. Select both circle and outlined K
4. Open Pathfinder (Window > Pathfinder) and select 'Minus Front'

[image: Minus front]

5. Done. Now you can use this on any background,

[image: Done]

6. **Optional**: the figure is now a group. You can make it a compound path if you'd rather have one object to work with. (Object > Compound path > Make)

Answer (score 1):

extend the lines of the 'K' to beyond the boundaries of the circle before intersecting.

this issue is caused because the boundaries of each shape are on top of each other but not quite identical (it would appear the 'K' is fractionally smaller than the circle)

when subtracting from above it's often worth leaving overhang to avoid situations like this :)

Comment: I extend the lines of the "k", but i still have the same problem.
(http://i.imgur.com/xHHD5qZ.png)